# Difference between Dashboard and My profile

Tags: liferay, portal

I have been using Liferay portal. Its very easy and user friendly. Actually developer friendly ! But i have few doubts. Would want to get them clarified.

1. What is the difference between dashboard and my profile?
2. How do you restrict a user from adding portlets? 
   3.How to add animation effects/slideshow ?

   yeah. That is all for now. Please help me get them clarified. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Dashboard --> User's own Page, where user can have own set of portlets

My Profile --> Basically Users's Information Page, where user can add/edit them manually.

for more info :

[User Personal Sites](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/user-personal-sites-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-07-en)

Comment: If this is what you are looking for, mark as answer, so others can refer it.

Answer (score 1):

The provided answer is not correct.  My Profile is a page where you can add portlets. My Dashboard is a page where you can add portlets.  See the difference?  Neither do I. After much digging I found this:
Finally, the user section shows the users name and provides links to the user’s profile (his or her publicly-accessible pages), dashboard (his or her private pages) ...
https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/touring-liferay-portals-user-interface

So it looks like "My Profile" = publicly-accessible pages, while
"My Dashboard" = private pages.  For an admin user, the dashboard appears to
contain links/portlets to manage the website, user accounts, etc.